# Error message "The device is not ready" when running Azure devops release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have moved a website to a new on-prem server and I'm currently trying to make CI/CD work. The release pipeline was already configured since we have been using Azure devops for years. So the only thing I needed to do was to register the new server in the development group. I ran the registration script, added the proper tags and didn't set a specific account for the Windows service so the default account **NT Authorization\System** was used.
The problem is that when a release is triggered, the service doesn't seem to be able to list the site as part of the Manage IISwebsite task. It throws a weird error "*The device is not ready*". It does though manage to change the apppool. See the logs below:

[image: Logs from the Manage IISWebsite step]

I have ran the command myself directly on the server using my admin account and it works just fine. The **NT Authorization\System** is a super user and should have all rights granted by default as well, so I'm a bit clueless here..
Does anybody have any ideas, suggestions? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

/Kenia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case the error message was misleading.

It turned out that the **Physical path** in the release pipeline was wrong. It worked after I changed it to the correct one.